# What is the regular expression for a total 10 digit number with a decimal precision of 1 or 2?

Tags: regex

I am trying a regex that satisfy the following for a total 10 digit number.
Tried this so far :

```
^(\d){0,8}(\.){0,1}(\d){0,2}$
```

It works fine but fails if I give the following :

```
123456789.0
```

Valid example:

```
1234567890 (total 10 digits)
1234567.1  (total 8 digits)
12345678.10 (total 10 digits)
123456789.1 (total 10 digits)
```

Invalid example :
12345678901 (11 characters)

Comment: Questions starting with `I want`, showing no effort are usually not well received

Comment: Why is `1234567.1  (total 8 digits)` a valid example?

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Comment: minimum 1 and max 9999999999 (10 digits) is valid. So 123456789.9 is valid. 99999999.99 is the max allowed num.

Comment: So, you want a total of up to 10 digits with zero or one decimal point in the last three positions?

Comment: Yes total 10 digits including decimals. Decimals can be 1 digit or 2 digit at max.

Comment: @baao I am using this expression in HTML angular expression. ng-pattern-restrict="^(\d){0,8}(\.){0,1}(\d){0,2}$"

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to go:

```
^(?:\d{1,10}|(?=\d+\.\d\d?$)[\d.]{3,11})$
```

**Explanation:**

```
 ^                  : begining of string
   (?:              : start non capture group
     \d{1,10}       : 1 upto 10 digits
     |              : OR
     (?=            : start look ahead
       \d+\.\d\d?$  : 1 or more digits then a dot then 1 or 2 digits
     )              : end lookahead
     [\d.]{3,11}    : only digit or dot are allowed, with a length from 3 upto 11
   )                : end group
 $                  : end of string
```

**In action:**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Modern::Perl;

my $re = qr~^(?:\d{1,10}|(?=\d+\.\d\d?$)[\d.]{3,11})$~;
while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    say (/$re/ ? "OK: $_" : "KO: $_");
}
__DATA__
1
123
1.2
1234567890
1234567.1
12345678.10
123456789.1
12345678901
1.2.3
```

**Output:**

```
OK: 1
OK: 123
OK: 1.2
OK: 1234567890
OK: 1234567.1
OK: 12345678.10
OK: 123456789.1
KO: 12345678901
KO: 1.2.3
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution using `String.prototype.match()` and `RegExp.prototype.text()` functions:

```js
var isValid = function (num) {
    return /^\d+(\.\d+)?$/.test(num) && String(num).match(/\d/g).length <= 10;
};

console.log(isValid(1234567890));
console.log(isValid(12345678.10));
console.log(isValid(12345678901));
console.log(isValid('123d3457'));
```

Comment: This will fail against `123.123123`

Answer (score 0):

you can break your pattern in 3 step:

**First step**
You need at least 8 digit + 1 or 2 precision that both are optional
`\d{8}\.?\d?\d?` Here `.` and both digit are optional

**Second step**
You need at least 9 digit + 1 precision and that's it
`\d{9}\.?\d?` Here `.` and digit are optional

Then you can mix these three rule together with or `|` keyword

`^(\d{8}\.?\d?\d?|\d{9}\.?\d?)$`

Okay now this **regex** only matches 7 to 10 digit with 1 or 2 precision
It never matches less than 8 digit and a tricky part is here that you can change **second step** `\d{8}` with `\d{1,8}` and then It match from 1 to 9999999999 and plus 1 or 2 precision.

**what you want:**
`^(\d{1,8}\.?\d?\d?|\d{9}\.?\d?)$`

```
echo 1 | perl -lne '/^(\d{1,8}\.?\d?\d?|\d{9}\.?\d?)$/ && print $&'
1
echo 9999999999 | perl -lne '/^(\d{1,8}\.?\d?\d?|\d{9}\.?\d?)$/ && print $&'
9999999999
echo 1.1 | perl -lne '/^(\d{1,8}\.?\d?\d?|\d{9}\.?\d?)$/ && print $&'
1.1
echo 1.12 | perl -lne '/^(\d{1,8}\.?\d?\d?|\d{9}\.?\d?)$/ && print $&'
1.12
echo 1234567.1 | perl -lne '/^(\d{1,8}\.?\d?\d?|\d{9}\.?\d?)$/ && print $&'
1234567.1
echo 1234567.12 | perl -lne '/^(\d{1,8}\.?\d?\d?|\d{9}\.?\d?)$/ && print $&'
1234567.12
echo 99999999.9 | perl -lne '/^(\d{1,8}\.?\d?\d?|\d{9}\.?\d?)$/ && print $&'
99999999.9
echo 99999999.99 | perl -lne '/^(\d{1,8}\.?\d?\d?|\d{9}\.?\d?)$/ && print $&'
99999999.99
```

**not match**

```
echo 1.111 | perl -lne '/^(\d{1,8}\.?\d?\d?|\d{9}\.?\d?)$/ && print $&'
echo 1234567.111 | perl -lne '/^(\d{1,8}\.?\d?\d?|\d{9}\.?\d?)$/ && print $&'
echo 123456781.11 | perl -lne '/^(\d{1,8}\.?\d?\d?|\d{9}\.?\d?)$/ && print $&'
echo 1234567891.1 | perl -lne '/^(\d{1,8}\.?\d?\d?|\d{9}\.?\d?)$/ && print $&'
echo 123456789101 | perl -lne '/^(\d{1,8}\.?\d?\d?|\d{9}\.?\d?)$/ && print $&'
```